# Using an IF Statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have the below SQL statement. What I would like to do is include an IF statement to cover the possibility of one of the columns returning a 0 or blank result, there are no 0 ID's. In this case, I'm trying to cover the possibility of the `magez_cfv_nations` result possibly returning a zero or blank result.

```
SELECT c.clan_name, n.nation_name, 
    CONCAT(r.rarity_shorthand, " - ", r.rarity_name) AS rarity_text, 
    t.trigger_name, s.skill_name
 FROM `magez_cfv_cards` AS cards
 JOIN `magez_cfv_clans` c ON cards.clan_id = c.clan_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_nations` n ON cards.nation_id = n.nation_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_rarity` r ON cards.rarity_id = r.rarity_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_trigger` t ON cards.trigger_id = t.trigger_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_skills` s ON cards.skill_id = s.skill_id
```

Comment: Are you talking about left joins?

Comment: I guess that it would sound like. Would I just use `LEFT JOIN` instead of JOIN up above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)

> The LEFT JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table
>   (table_name1), even if there are no matches in the right table

Try this

```
SELECT c.clan_name, n.nation_name, 
    CONCAT(r.rarity_shorthand, " - ", r.rarity_name) AS rarity_text, 
    t.trigger_name, s.skill_name
 FROM `magez_cfv_cards` AS cards
 JOIN `magez_cfv_clans` c ON cards.clan_id = c.clan_id
 LEFT JOIN `magez_cfv_nations` n ON cards.nation_id = n.nation_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_rarity` r ON cards.rarity_id = r.rarity_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_trigger` t ON cards.trigger_id = t.trigger_id
 JOIN `magez_cfv_skills` s ON cards.skill_id = s.skill_id
```

Answer (score 1):

the function you should use is `IIF()` and its syntax is

```
IIF([condition],[if true],[if false])
```